# Numerals: how to read and understand

Tags: meaning, questions, british-english, reading, numerals

Please, help me to puzzle it out:)
I've read the sentense in the text about school:
"There are about one 600 pupils". The author writes how large the school is.
I understand the meaning of the phrase, but don't know how to read and understand "one 600 pupils" - does it mean "one thousand and six hundred"? 
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Context is essential to meaning; where did you read this sentence? What are the surrounding sentences? It currently makes no sense; you would not normally write "about one 600 pupils," but we have no idea what was intended. Please [edit] your post to include more detail.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for answering! I've edited the post and I hope it's more informative now)

Comment: Are you certain you are transcribing faithfully? *About 1 600* would be conventional, and *about one-six hundred* can be explained, but *about one 600* is neither here nor there, and would be taken as erroneous, so there is no way to know what the intended meaning is unless you ask the author.

Comment: Yeah, there's something wrong with the text, I guess... But it was taken from our English text book) Thank you very much!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a standard way of expressing a number. You must say "one thousand six hundred" if you mean 1600.  (it is possible to say sixteen hundred but this is rarer).

It is not possible to say "one six hundred" to mean 1600, or any other number. So the quoted text contains a mistake that makes it hard to understand.  It could be a mistaken way of saying "one thousand six hundred", or it could a speaking error (The speaker meant to say 600, but accidentally said "one", then corrected himself)

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer!:)